# Evento click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou tentando usar o jQuery para fazer algo como:

```
if($('#id').click) {
    //Eu sei que quando este elemento 
    //for clicado ele vai fazer algo aqui, mas, eu queria em um 
    //outro momento fora da função saber se foi clicado ou não
}

if($('#id2').click) {

    }
```

EX:

```
    if($('#id').***clicked*** {

}
```

Eu preciso testar qual dos dois foi clicado pois vou chamar no mesmo HTML.
Por exemplo:

```
$('foto)'.click(function(){
     if($('#id').clicked){
          function1();
     }
     if($('#id2').clicked){  
          function2();
     }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi, pra que você precisa do `if` e `else`? se o cara não clicar automaticamente seria o `else` e se a pessoa clicar seria o `if`, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Olá, qual a intenção do segundo click? Não pode fazer todas as funções necessárias pós click em um lugar só?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta para explicar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Da maneira como a pergunta foi feita fica difícil deduzir se você quer:

- O mesmo handler porém que saiba se qual botão foi clicado;
- O mesmo handler porém que se saiba o estado dos botões.

Se for o primeiro caso você pode usar parâmetro `data` do método [`jQuery.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/). Dessa maneira você pode passar dados personalizados para o handler de evento.

Ex.:

```js
let $botao_1 = $('#btn-1');
let $botao_2 = $('#btn-2');

function click_handler(event) {
  console.log(event.data.texto);
}

$botao_1.on('click', { texto: "Você clicou no botão 1" }, click_handler);
$botao_2.on('click', { texto: "Você clicou no botão 2" }, click_handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-1">Botão 1</button>
<button id="btn-2">Botão 2</button>
```

Caso você queira saber o estados dos botões você pode usar o método [`jQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) para atribuir e recuperar dados de um objeto jQuery. Ex.:

```js
let $botao_1 = $('#btn-1');
let $botao_2 = $('#btn-2');
let $botoes = $botao_1.add($botao_2);  // apenas cria um "grupo" com os dois botões

function click_handler(event) {
  // converte um HTMLElement para um objeto jQuery
  let $this = $(this);
  
  // Recupera a quantidade de clicks, senão houver recebe zero
  let clicks = $this.data('clicks') || 0;
  
  // Incrementa 'clicks' no botão clicado
  $this.data('clicks', clicks + 1);

  // Apenas para visualização dos dados
  console.log('Clicks no botão 1: ' + $botao_1.data('clicks'));
  console.log('Clicks no botão 2: ' + $botao_2.data('clicks'));
  console.log('-----');
}

$botoes.on('click', click_handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-1">Botão 1</button>
<button id="btn-2">Botão 2</button>
```

---

Utilizei o método [`jQuery.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) para não precisar executar outra pesquisa no DOM e para fins de curiosidade, mas você poderia ter usado um seletor de classes como `$('.meus-botoes')` que também funcionaria.

Answer (score 0):

Uma variável global resolveria seu problema:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#primeiro').click(function() {
      teste = 1;
    }));

  if ($('#segundo').click(function() {
      teste = 2;
    }));

  $('#foto').click(function() {
    alert(" O " + teste + " foi clicado");
    if (teste = 1) {
      /*function1()*/
    } else if (teste = 2) {
      /*function2()*/
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="primeiro">Primeiro</div>
  <div id="segundo">Segundo</div>
  <button id="foto">Clique Aqui</button>
</body>
</html>
```